# Display image in Template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I've been trying to display in my template an image that is stored in my model. but I can't. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

**model.py**:

```
class DeviceType(models.Model):
    type_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64, unique=True)
    type_description = models.TextField(max_length=512, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("devices:type-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})


class DeviceTypeImage(models.Model):
    image_status = IntegerField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/types/')
    image_device_type = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='image')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image_status)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("devices:type-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

**view.py**:

```
class DeviceTypeDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'devices/type-detail.html'
    model = DeviceType

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(DeviceType, pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
```

**template**:

```
<h1>Type detail</h1>

{{ object.type_name }}<br>
{{ object.type_description }}<br>
{{ object.image_status }}<br>
{{ object.image_device_type }}

<img src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="...">
```

**urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: `object` is a `DeviceType`, not a `DeviceTypeImage`.

Comment: And how can i access my image in the template? isn't the DeviceTypeImage model accessed automatically when calling get_object_or_404(DeviceType, pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))?

Comment: well since it is a `ForeignKey`, there is not an image: a `DeviceType` can have *zero*, one, or *more* related `DeviceTypeImage`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` is a `DeviceType`, not a `DeviceTypeImage`. A `DeviceType` can furthermore have *multiple* `DeviceTypeImage`s, so `object.image` is a *manager* of `DeviceTypeImage`s: it can wrap *zero*, one or multiple images.

You thus access the images with:

```
{{ object.type_name }}<br>
{{ object.type_description }}<br>

{% for image in object.image.all %}
    {{ image.image_status }}
    <img src="{{ image.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```